# Installing TensorFlow Profiler for Dummies

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, tensorboard

I am trying to follow this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler) to install the TensorFlow Profiler to better understand why my recently installed Keras does run on the GPU, but hardly uses any ressources (and is really slow). However, I am unable to come to any results, since the guide does not provide me with sufficient information, since I am not a programmer by trade and obiously lack necessary knowledge.

What have I tried so far?
I use Anaconda and have a running version of python 3.7 installed. I also installed tensorflow and the necessary drivers and such so that tensorflow is able to access my GPUs. Following the linked guide, I downloaded the "install_and_run.py" and tried executing it using the conda prompt. I get asked to specify --envdir and --logdir. Where do I point these? Is the environment directory just the directory to my current conda environment? Since I tried pointing both envdir and logdir into that direction and ended up with the error that the command

> True" is unknown and "True' returned non-zero exit status 1.

I could not come up with any solution for this. It should probably be mentioned that I have very little experience in using the conda prompt to run .py-files and usually only use it to install packages.

I am also unsure what is meant by the subsequent steps that talk about the CUPTI path. The given path is no complete path as far as i know. Where am I supposed to look for it? Or am I meant to exectute some of this

```
/sbin/ldconfig -N -v $(sed 's/:/ /g' <<< $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) | \
grep libcupti
```

as a command? I have tried running `/sbin/ldconfig -N -v $` but my system could not find the path (potentially because I started looking from the wrong directory?).

Any help is much appreciated. Sorry for the potentially confusing post from a confused person.

Thank you!

Comment: You're meant to execute this command : `/sbin/ldconfig -N -v $(sed 's/:/ /g' <<< $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) | grep libcupti`. Did you do it?

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow profiler is no longer bundled with Tensorboard. There is a [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras) on how to install and run it, when fitting Keras model.

The summary is:

1. Inside your env run `pip install tensorboard_plugin_profile`
2. Declare a tensorboard callback as you normally would

```py
tboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = logs,
                                                 histogram_freq = 1,
                                                 profile_batch = '500,520')
```

3. Fit your model (with declared tensorboard callback)
4. On a separe terminal (with your env activated) run `tensorboard --logdir=path/to/logs`

The Profiler tab shown in the tutorial may not be visisble, but there should be a profile option available in the drop down menu on the top right corner.

Comment: Thanks for prividing me with the link to the tutorial. I followed it step by step and did not run into any issues. However, in the end, my tensorboard simply does not include an active "profile" tab.

Under the dropdown menu on the right titled "inactive" I can navigate to "profile" and get the message: **The profile plugin has moved. Please install the new version of the profile plugin from PyPI by running the following command from the machine running TensorBoard: pip install -U tensorboard-plugin-profile**. Running this tells me that all the requirements are already satisfied. Any advice?

Comment: You could try to reinstall it with `pip install --ignore-installed tensorboard-plugin-profile`. Other than that I don't know that could cause this issue.

Comment: I did that and now end up with errors within the "profiles page". So there is progress!
**Failed to load libcupti (is it installed and accessible?)**
and
**No step marker observed and hence the step time is unknown.[...]***
Any more advice? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm, can you run [these steps](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#install_the_profiler_and_gpu_prerequisites) in the tutorial you linked? Also, this could be an [Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43030#issuecomment-736206189) with Tensorflow.